# What is technology to make our website available when user is offline?

Tags: html, web, browser

I've seen such technology as Whatsapp Web that we still can access even if we are not connect to the internet. It will show "Your computer not connected to internet" with html and css of that web rather than show the default browser error "No internet connection". My question is, what technology to make that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this technology under the name progressive web app and service-worker, in relation to webdesign.

[article](https://alligator.io/js/intro-progressive-web-apps/),
[example with angular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=othhfZ0mGjU)

Comment: First I go to [Application Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) but there are deprecation warning, and recommend me to go to the [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)

Answer (score 1):

ti is possible with Cache manifest in HTML5.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5

Answer (score 1):

Cache manifest in HTML5 is the thing that you are looking for.

```html
<!—- test.html -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="cache.appcache">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  Testing the manifest file.
</body>
</html>
```

some of the useful link that you can use.
[Using_the_application_cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)

[A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)